# Export the chat history logs from thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, export

I would like to export all chat logs from my Thunderbird installation, so I can

- backup addressbook and chat-logs
- re-install a clean new Thunderbird
- re-add my IMAP acounts and chat-accounts
- reimport the chat-history and addressbook

(addressbook already is easy to be eported)

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly straightforward process. Location of the logs differs on various operating systems however.

For a Windows 7 machine the logs are in the following place:

C:\Users*UserName*\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles*UserProfile*\logs

On Ubuntu they can be found in:

~/.thunderbird/{{your profile}}/logs/

Exporting is a simple enough matter. Just copy the logs you want from the first machine and paste into the correct location in the second machine.

**Things to look out for:**

- On the second machine make sure you have logged into irc at least once.
- make sure that you have set up your irc account to connect to the correct rooms - otherwise there isn't anywhere for your logs file contents to display
- With irc logs check before you paste every folder. Every time you connect to a chatroom you generate a new folder. You might not be interested in every one.

Answer (score 0):

### ~ UNTESTED ~

There is a log folder in your Thunderbird profile folder:

```
~/.thunderbird/{{your profile}}/logs/
```

That contains all aim,  facebook,  gtalk,  icq,  irc,  jabber,  msn,  twitter, ...
chat-logs

Backup that folder and restore it after a fresh install.